# SQL | SUM duplicates on diffrent keys

Tags: sql

I'm new to SQL and I couldn't figure how to do this.
I would like to sum a coulmn called "total_spending" for similar pairs (vin, action)
Here's a screenshot

[image]

INPUT :

```
action  dealer_name   vin    Total_spending reference month year 
A1      D1            V1         T1             R1     M1    Y1
A2      D2            V2         T2             R1     M1    Y1
A2      D2            V2         T3             R1     M1    Y1
A3      D2            V1         T4             R1     M1    Y1
A4      D1            V2         T5             R1     M1    Y1
A2      D1            V2         T6             R1     M1    Y1
A1      D1            V1         T7             R1     M1    Y1
A4      D1            V2         T8             R1     M1    Y1
A1      D1            V1         T9             R1     M1    Y1
A3      D2            V2         T10            R1     M1    Y1
A3      D2            V1         T11            R1     M1    Y1
```

Output:

```
action  dealer_name   vin    Total_spending reference month year 
A1      D1            V1         T1 + T7 + T9   R1     M1    Y1
A2      D2            V2         T2 + T3        R1     M1    Y1
A3      D2            V1         T4 + T11       R1     M1    Y1
A4      D1            V2         T5 + T8        R1     M1    Y1
A2      D1            V2         T6             R1     M1    Y1
A3      D2            V2         T10            R1     M1    Y1
```

Comment: Use `sum` in combination with `GROUP BY vin, action` ? Which dbms are you using? What have you tried? And please don't post screenshots, because that makes it imposible to cut and paste testdata for us. Always post some sample data as text.

Comment: Please show us the results that you expect.

Comment: | action | dealer_name| vin | total_spending | reference | ... | month |  ***********

| A1      | D1                | V1 |          T1            | R1            | ... |  M1    |    **********   

| A1      |  D1               | V1 |          T2          | R1            | ... |  M1    |        *********

Comment: Expected output is : For each pair (action, vin ) --> sum(total_spending)

| action | dealer_name| vin | total_spending | reference | ... | month |
+--------+------------+-----+----------------+-----------+-----+-------+         
| A1     | D1         | V1  | T1 +T 2                     | R1           | ... | M1    |

Comment: @Jaeger_007 do you want to match the pairs up by the issue date as well? Or is it just action and vin?

Comment: Hello @ARedfearn , I would like to match ussing unique pair (vin, action) you can look to the example I provided, Input and Output ( databse type hadoop - hive )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` determining the columns by which you want to group your sum.

```
SELECT SUM(total_spending) AS "Total_Spending" FROM table GROUP BY vin, action
```

> replace table with your table's name

This should work for MSSQL.

Syntax may slightly differ depending on the dbms you are using.

Comment: it's for hadoop - hive

Answer (score 0):

You have to do sum with group by,

```
SELECT pair, SUM(total_spending)
  FROM table_data group by pair;
```

Thanks